# $request->ajax() returns false on ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, axios, middleware

I am making a ajax request with `axios` to a `laravel` `controller`, i want to use a `middleware` to check if the `request` was made with `ajax`, but the problem is that when i make an `ajax request,` the `middleware` throws `false` always.

i make the call like this

```
axios.post('/api/contact/send', {
    ...
    data : data
}).then((response) => {
    Do somethings
}).catch(err => {
    Do somethings
})
```

my api routes

```
Route::namespace('Home')->middleware('IsAjaxRequest')->domain(env('HOST'))->group(function(){
    ....
    Route::post('contact/send','ContactController@postContact');
});
```

the `IsAjaxRequest` middleware

```
if(!$request->ajax()) {
    abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
}
return $next($request);
```

and the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Home;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Events\Home\ContactMail;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Http\Requests\ContactRequest;
class ContactController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function postContact(ContactRequest $request)
    {

        $data  = $request->all();
        event(new ContactMail($request->all()));
        return response()->json();
    }
}
```

if i take out the `middleware`, everything will work fine, the problem is when i check `$request->ajax()` that return `false`, i have checked it outside the `middleware` directly in the `controlelr` but the result is the same, what's wrong? why return `false` if the call was made via ajax?

Comment: Have you registered the middleware? Please update question with complete middleware code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Axios does not send the `X-Requested-With` header that Laravel looks for to determine if the request is AJAX.

If you ask me you should not use or rely on this header at all but (I guess) for the purposes of easy migration away from jQuery (which does include the header) the basic Laravel boilerplate [bootstrap.js](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js) has code:

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

which ensures all requests made with Axios get this header, however if you are not using that file you need to run this line in your own script.